# Getting query-string parameters in managed beans

Tags: jsf, query-string

I've got trouble with getting URL param in JSF / PrimeFaces.

That works fine for all my pages, except for one where I cant get URL param

My URL is like this

```
/path/to/my/page?id=99
```

My bean class is annoted with

```
@Named
@ViewRequest
```

I do it this way in the `@PostConstruct` method

```
Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String id = params.get("id");
```

but params do not contain `id`

Instead of having URL param names in the params Map, I have other values like these

```
[0]javax.faces.partial.render=...
[1]javax.faces.partial.execute=...
[2]j_idt20=...
[3]javax.faces.ViewState=...
```

Does someone have an idea about this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your JSF page, you can process the params similar to

## page.xhtml

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

## Page

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private String id;

    // getter and setter
}
```

Comment: thanks for yout suggestion. I tried but the value is null like when I get  it the other way.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the setter whether the parameter gets really set by the `viewParam` or not?

Comment: when i put breakpoint in the setter, I see that the setter is well called with the good value, and the PostConstruct method is called before the param setter. that is why i cant get the value in the PostContruct
I tried many different modifications and it seam that now it works.
I can get the param threw my first method when the viewparam is declared in the page.xhtml
I dont know why.

Comment: Well, actually this works as expected, as a bean is constructed before the actual page is being evaluated, so how should the `@PostConstruct` method know about page params? Our solution is a combination of `f:viewParam` and `f:viewAction` if we want to execute code basing on a given URL param.